# How should I stretch a letter "o" horizontally in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, typography, distort

There are other questions here answering similar issues, but in this case, creating outlines and then just moving the anchor point is distorting the letter.

[image: anchor points]

[image: dragging result]

Comment: Stretching the letter _is_ distorting it. You can’t stretch it without distorting it.

Comment: If you want more of a rounded rectangle, use the Rounded Rectangle tool and add a stroke.

Answer (score 1):

If it is an actual letter O (as in type) that you want to stretch horizontally then open the character panel (Window>Type>Character) and adjust the horizontal scaling- it is the 3rd down from the top on the right side of the dialog box- this will distort the letter- [image]

If this distortion is not what you want then you can use the scissors tool (C) to cut he center anchor points of your outlined shape (the top right picture you posted above) then you can select one half of the outlined letter and move it horizontally and rejoin the anchor points- again the letter form will be distorted-
[image]

Otherwise as @Scott says in the comment make a shape and do not try and modify a "letter"

Comment: The cutting/rejoining option is what I was looking for, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Not really clear what you're trying to achieve, but after converting to outlines, use the Selection tool <kbd>V</kbd> (instead of the Direct Selection tool <kbd>A</kbd>). Drag from that edge handle, where it says "anchor" in pink.

[image]

And you'll get something like this:

[image]

Comment: You must go to  View>Show Bounding Box  and click it for this to work- and then it is not even necessary to outline your type- just select it and drag the side handle of the bounding box- if you hold option (or alt) while dragging it will stretch from the center (both horizontal directions)

Comment: Bounding box is generally shown by default, and yeah you don't need to outline for this to work. I was just trying to stick to what the OP wrote, you know new users can sometimes get confused if you write something else.

Answer (score 0):

Use the node-pulling method in order not to distort the original letter in an unwanted fashion.

Just select the Direct Selection tool in order to drag individual nodes to reshape the letter, after converting it to outlines. That's what I meant.

Comment: What is "the node-pulling method"? Perhaps show an example.

Comment: Just select the Direct Selection tool in order to drag individual nodes to reshape the letter, after converting it to outlines. That's what I meant.

Comment: @Mosh please [edit] your answer to add this information.